# Razor Components and Tag Helpers, Why? How?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-tag-helpers, asp.net-core-3.1, razor-components

Reading the latest documentation for ASP.Net Core 3.1, it is now recommended to use Razor Components over View Components.  From 1,000 feet, this looks like a great idea as there is a single-file now instead of a "controller" and a default "view".  More precise, compact, and I am assuming more efficient.

One big of information that took me by surprise, was the fact that tag helpers aren't supported in Razor Components ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#tag-helpers-arent-used-in-components)):

> Tag Helpers aren't supported in Razor components (.razor files). To provide Tag Helper-like functionality in Blazor, create a component with the same functionality as the Tag Helper and use the component instead.

Am I the only one in all of the .NET world that thinks this is absolutely not acceptable?  In view components, tag helpers are supported and are the single-most useful bits of .NET MVC.  A simple example  is the [anchor tag helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.1).  That is the most useful helper in my opinion as it accepts `area`, `controller`, `action`, and a dynamic parameter list that generates an anchor tag without you having to worry about figuring out the routing.

Enough griping, to turn this into a question, how would one do this now in a Razor Component?  The example on Microsoft's documentation for the tag helper is the ability to create a navigational menu using the tag helpers in a view component.  Now, on the view component page, it is recommended to use Razor Components over View Components ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#view-components)):

> When considering if view components meet an app's specifications, consider using Razor Components instead. Razor Components also combine markup with C# code to produce reusable UI units. Razor Components are designed for developer productivity when providing client-side UI logic and composition.

So, if one were to create a navigational menu in ASP.NET Core 3.1 (MVC) using Razor Components, what would be the easiest way to accomplish this without having to document every single route in Startup?

Comment: Razor Components is for blazor project, do you mean you want to add blazor support  to your mvc project?

Comment: Well, maybe I misunderstood the Microsoft documentation because the page was for ASP.NET Core 3.1 and on the View Component page.  It says they recommend you use Razor Components instead.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe you could refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59328798/razor-components-vs-view-components).Razor component is more powerful but you need to add [blazor support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#integrate-components-into-razor-pages-and-mvc-apps) in order to use it.